# Cucumber step definition for "Given that I'm logged in"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber

I've got a cucumber step: Given that I'm logged in

I don't understand how I should implement it as a step definition.

Could someone point me into right direction, tutorials, blogs etc.

Comment: Need to know what authentication system you are using

Answer (score 9, accepted):

here is how I do it.

```
Given /^I have one\s+user "([^\"]*)" with email "([^\"]*)" and password "([^\"]*)"$/ do |username,email, password|
  @user = User.new(:email => email,
                   :username=>username,
                   :password => password,
                   :password_confirmation => password)
   @user.save!
end

Given /^I am an authenticated user$/ do
  name = 'exmample'
  email = 'example@example.com'
  password = 'secret!'

  Given %{I have one user "#{name}" with email "#{email}" and password "#{password}"}
  And %{I go to the user login page}
  And %{I fill in "user_username" with "#{name}"}
  And %{I fill in "user_password" with "#{password}"}
  And %{I press "Sign in"}
end
```

The reason I do it this way, is that I run through the entire stack and set the environment up the way a normal user would...

Answer (score 4):

Hi You may divide this step into three smaller steps

```
1. visit login page
2. fill_in login, username
3. press login button
```