# How to write this logic as Cucumber features?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cucumber step definition for “Given that I’m logged in”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496500/cucumber-step-definition-for-given-that-im-logged-in)

I have a page I want to test links and forms in it, but that page is only available to logged in users. 
So I need to create a user, log him in, then visit the page to start the test. 
If I put this code in the "Background" it will execute before each scenario. Which I think is too expensive.

If I add a hook, like this, it will also execute before each scenario

**features file:**

```
@tag
Feature: feature x

Scenario:
  Given ...
  When ...
  Then ...
```

**hooks.rb file:**

```
Before '@tag' do
  step "I am a logged in user"
end
```

So my question is: Is there a way I can make "create user, login user" only execute once for all the scenarios that follow? Thanks!

Comment: Unless setting up or bootstrapping data, I'd probably opt out of doing it. You lose isolation this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a before hook and keep track of its previous execution like this:

```
Before "@tag" do
  unless $before_all_done
    # do your thing
    $before_all_done = true
  end
end
```

See https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks for more information on Hooks.